# Best way to make this (trapezoid) shape in css3

Tags: css, shapes, pseudo-element

I have this shape with pseudo elements:

https://jsfiddle.net/6gf1m3j5/

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background:#ccc;
}

#octagon-left {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
#octagon-left::before {
    border-left: 100px solid white;
    border-top: 60px solid red;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 40px;
}

#octagon-left::after {
    border-right: 100px solid white;
    border-top: 60px solid red;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 40px;
}
```

The problem here is the white color in the left and right corner.

If I do, border-left: 100px solid transparent; the color red is prevailing.

I want to like this:
[image]

How can I do that?

I really appreciate your support, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#octagon
{
  background-color: red;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
}
#octagon:before,
#octagon:after
{
  background-color: red;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#octagon:before
{
  transform: translateX(30px) skewX(-45deg);
}
#octagon:after
{
  transform: translateX(-30px) skewX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="octagon"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Comment: I have a little issue here, if I add 100%(full width) to: #octagon
{
  width: 100%;
}  this not work, I need like my example but with transparent. https://jsfiddle.net/6gf1m3j5/

Comment: @Thenothing Do you have any other specs e.g. whether the height is fixed or something?

Comment: Hi Mohit Bhardwaj, first of all, I appreciate your participation, about the height is ok 60px.

Comment: @Thenothing Thanks. Please check the updated code if that works for you. Here I have used css `calc`  function and defined width and translateX values based on the height of the div. So, if height is 60px, you need to use `width: calc(100% - 120px);` and translateX value as half of the height i.e. 30px.

Comment: I have done this before, but in other way: https://jsfiddle.net/re5ssn37/  I want to know if there is another alternative to calc.

Comment: @Thenothing That's a nice solution. I have updated your fiddle -https://jsfiddle.net/re5ssn37/3/. I have removed `calc` and used `width: 50%` instead. I just had to add `box-sizing: border-box` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Change you code like so and let me know

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background:#ccc;
}

#octagon-left {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
#octagon-left::before {
    border-left: 100px solid #ccc;/*Change from white to #ccc*/
    border-top: 60px solid red;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 40px;
}

#octagon-left::after {
    border-right: 100px solid #ccc;/*Change from white to #ccc*/
    border-top: 60px solid red;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="octagon-left">

</div>
```

Comment: I have to set this shape after image background, this not work.

Comment: Seem I didn't understand your request. You want something same with your image is this ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message, the color #ccc is just a example, I have to set a image like background.

Comment: Oh alright, it should be done by another approach. You have the answer already?